# Force string data type when writing to CSV file

Tags: php, csv

In PHP, is there a way to force the value "00123" to be inserted into a CSV file as a string?

This way, when you open the CSV file the value will remain `00123` rather than removing the leading zeros and showing `123`.

The primary reason I'd like achieve this is for a list of zipcodes, whereas there are multiple zipcodes that have leading zeros and I'd like the values to reflect that.

```
<?php
if( $fh = fopen('filename.csv','w') ){

    $line = ['00123'];

    fputcsv($fh,$line);

    fclose($fh);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSV does not have types. Values written using the `,"..",` syntax merely delimit the value to disambiguate the usage of `,` within the value itself; it does not mean that the value is "a string".

I suspect your values are mangled when imported into Excel or such. There's no solution to this that CSV can offer; you can only import the file using the import wizard and specify that the column should be used as is and not cast to a number. (This may or may not actually work depending on what effed-up version of Excel you're using.)

If you don't want to go through this every time, you should be producing an XLSX file, which *does* have types.

Comment: The values are being transformed in `Excel`. Opening the file using just a plain text editor shows the desired results. Thanks for the explanation and alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way to do it because "CSV" files are just "Comma-Separated Values"

You have to use the editor options for csv import.